# UML diagram from a Visual Studio 2013 solution

Tags: database, uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram

I am building an N-Tier generic application that has an ASP.NET MVC 4 client and data access, business, layers etc consisting of class libraries.

I would like to generate class diagrams (a bit like the .edmx files). for the entire solution to show the architecture in an easy to understand way.

Any tools out there for this ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio Premium or Universal, VS itself will let you create Structure and Static Class Diagrams, plus I think Sequence Diagrams.

There are a number of third party tools which will import C# code but they tend not to be free (they may have free versions, but the Import C# functionality isn't included). Examples of these are Sparx Enterprise Architect and Visual Paradigm.

Older versions of Visio used to do it, but I think Visio 2013 doesn't any more.